# Pygame: Move object towards position

Tags: python, animation, pygame, game-physics

Is there an algorithm to change a set of coordinates to make it move towards another set of coordinates?

Like, if I have `ax,ay=(20,30)` and `bx,by=(40,60)`

I can't seem to wrap my head around this. How can I change `ax` and `ay` (over time) to equal `bx` and `by`?
(Preferably an algorithm achievable in python.)

Comment: Do you mean, to `a` to "chase" `b`?

Comment: you want ax,ay to become 21,31 22,32 ... 39,59 ?

Comment: Yes, essentially I want it to "chase" !

Answer (score 8):

It's pretty easy if you think about it. To create the illusion of *movement* you need to create an animation - that is, moving the object **step by step**.

The object needs to move 20 pixels horizontally (`bx - ax = 20`) and 30 pixels vertically (`by - ay = 60`). Now, you need to define how many *steps* the object will spend moving. That essentially depends on the framerate of your game, if you want the animation to last 1 second and your game runs at 25fps, the animation will take 25 steps. If your game does not have a fixed framerate but something else, you'll need to compute the amount of movement for each iteration of the **game loop** depending on the elapsed time from the last frame.

Let's suppose we're runing at a fixed speed of 25fps. In that case, you'd need to do something like:

```
dx, dy = (bx - ax, by - ay)
stepx, stepy = (dx / 25., dy / 25.)
```

Now, `stepx` and `stepy` have the amount of movement needed in each step. What you need to do is add that in each iteration of the game loop:

```
# In each iteration:
object.set_position(object.x + stepx, object.y + stepy)
```

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the speed? When I used this code, the objects just sat on top of the point as it moved.

Comment: You have to divide by smaller number than 25. to get less steps  **OR** you have to multiply steps `object.set_position(object.x + 2*stepx, object.y + 2*stepy)` and makes less iterations.

Answer (score 3):

```
steps_number = max( abs(bx-ax), abs(by-ay) )

stepx = float(bx-ax)/steps_number
stepy = float(by-ay)/steps_number

for i in range(steps_number+1):
    print int(ax + stepx*i), int(ay + stepy*i)
```

result:

```
20 30
20 31
21 32
22 33
22 34
23 35
24 36
24 37
25 38
26 39
26 40
27 41
28 42
28 43
29 44
30 45
30 46
31 47
32 48
32 49
33 50
34 51
34 52
35 53
36 54
36 55
37 56
38 57
38 58
39 59
40 60
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using pygame, then you can use vectors to move your object on the screen.

```py
import pygame as pg

vec = pg.math.Vector2
a = vec(20, 30)
b = vec(40, 60)
a += b
```

Put it in your loop and add speed to slow it down.
Your object will move toward the "b" point and will pass it when it reachs that point.

Comment: `vec(b)` won't work - vectors are not callable.

Comment: You are right, i added () by mistake.
So just use like this:
vec = pg.math.Vector2

You also can normalize the vector for smoother movement.

Comment: I actually meant your last line.  `pg.math.Vector2` instantiates an empty Vector, `pg.math.Vector2()` instantiates a vector with the values `(0, 0)` - so both versions work. What does not work is your line `a += vec(b)`.

Comment: Both "a" and "b" should be a vector then it have to work.

Comment: Corrected it. try this and it should work for you now. Sry for the problem.

Comment: @TrickyDeath I tried doing this but for some reason object "a" went MUCH faster than it should be

Comment: There are 2 different base movement. One is time base and other is frame base. It is depend which one are you using. I suggest you to use time base movement if it is multiplayer and the reason for this is simple. If any of the player PC lagging and you using frame base movement he will move slower then the other player who not lagging. Also as i mantioned above, add speed for the movement to speed it up or slow it down. This is the way how you can use speed buffs, or slow debuffs in game.

Answer (score 0):

In `pygame-ce` and `pygame` version `2.1.3` a vector method was introduced: `move_towards`, which does exactly what it says, it allows for convenient movement towards a target without overshooting the target location:

```py
pos_a = pygame.Vector2(20, 30)
pos_b = pygame.Vector2(40, 60)

# now every frame you can do this
pos_a = pos_a.move_towards(pos_b, velocity)

# or if you so wish you can also use the in-place method
pos_a.move_towards_ip(pos_b, velocity)
```

In both cases `pos_a` will eventually arrive at `pos_b` if it will remain static ofc and the velocity will be positive.

You can visit the documentation here: https://pyga.me/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.move_towards

For those interested in what's `pygame-ce`, it's basically better pygame: [announcement](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/1112q10/pygame_community_edition_announcement/)